# How does one access data from retired backends?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am having trouble retrieving data using Qiskit from jobs I ran on a currently retired system. However, I can still retrieve the same data from the dashboard (GUI), so I think the data are still there. For instance, the following code works just fine for retrieving counts data from an old job I ran on Melbourne (currently in service):

```
BACKEND='ibmq_16_melbourne'
JOB_ID='6009735f4ae4e567f432feca'
my_backend = provider.get_backend(BACKEND)
my_job = my_backend.retrieve_job(JOB_ID)
COUNTS = my_job.result().get_counts()
```

However, the same code but trying to retrieve data from a job that ran on Vigo fails:

```
BACKEND='ibmq_vigo'
JOB_ID='60037fbf2159c338e734e663'
my_backend = provider.get_backend(BACKEND)
my_job = my_backend.retrieve_job(JOB_ID)
COUNTS = my_job.result().get_counts()
```

The error message I get is

```
QiskitBackendNotFoundError: 'No backend matches the criteria'
```

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Thank you!

Jorge

Answer (score 3):

You can use `provider.backend.retrieve_job(JOB_ID)` to retrieve jobs from retired backends.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. In particular, `my_job=provider.backend.retrieve_job('60037fbf2159c338e734e663')` followed by `COUNTS = my_job.result().get_counts()` does what I wanted - and it works for non-retired backends as well. Thanks!